# Function object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am having the following problem: I'am creating a object contructor that creates a bullet, the thing is the "bullets" object is returning undefined on the console log when i try to use it. I'am out of ideas of what's wrong.

Sorry for the messy code and the bad english. And thanks in advance.
Edit: If you are going to down vote please tell me the reason so i can know how to improve.

```js
var canvas, ctx, Player,players, intervalo,x,y, keyUp,keyDown,keyLeft,keyRight,rX,rY,rRadius,rAngle,hei, orbitals, Orbital, mouseX, mouseY, tiros, Bullet, bullets;
keyUp = 87; keyDown = 83; keyRight = 68; keyLeft = 65;
hei = 0;
test = 0; tiros = 0;
function load(){
 canvas = document.getElementById('box');
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.lineWidth = 3;
 function player(){
  this.x = canvas.width/2;
  this.y = canvas.height/2;
  this.speed = 2;
  this.width = 10;
  this.height = 10;
  
  this.up = false;
  this.down = false;
  this.left = false;
  this.right = false;
 }
 function orbital(){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = 3;
  this.height = 3;
  this.radius = 20;
  this.angle = hei;
  this.speed = 0;
 }
 Orbital = new Array();
 for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
  Orbital.push(new orbital())
  orbitals = Orbital[i];
  hei += 10;
  orbitals.angle = hei;
 }
 Player = new Array();
 Player.push(new player())
 players = Player[0];
 window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyDown, false);
 function checkKeyDown(e) {
  if (event.keyCode == keyUp){
   players.up = true;
   console.log("Up key is pressed");
  } else if (event.keyCode == keyDown){
   players.down = true;
   console.log("Down key is pressed");
  } else if (event.keyCode == keyLeft){
   players.left = true;
   console.log("Left key is pressed");
  } else if (event.keyCode == keyRight){
   players.right = true;
   console.log("Right key is pressed");
  }
 }
 window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp, false); 
 function checkKeyUp(e){
  if (event.keyCode == keyUp){
   players.up = false;
   console.log("Up key is released");
  } else if (event.keyCode == keyDown){
   players.down = false;
   console.log("Down key is released");
  } else if (event.keyCode == keyLeft){
   players.left = false;
   console.log("Left key is released");
  } else if (event.keyCode == keyRight){
   players.right = false;
   console.log("Right key is released");
  }
 }
 document.onmousemove = mouseMove;//Detectando posição do mouse;
 function mouseMove(e) {
  e = e || window.event
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = mouseX + " " + mouseY;
 }
  //Here is where the bullet begins:
 function bullet(){ 
  this.x = players.x;
  this.y = players.y;
  this.width = 5;
  this.height = 5;
  this.speed = 20;
  var dX = mouseX - players.x;
  var dY = mouseY - players.y;
  var distance = Math.sqrt(dX*dX + dY*dY);
  this.speedX = (dX/distance) * 10;
  this.speedY = (dY/distance) * 10;
 }
 Bullet = new Array();
 canvas.onmousedown = function () {
        Bullet.push(new bullet()) 
  tiros++;
  bullets = Bullet[tiros];
  document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = tiros;
    };
}
function play(){
 intervalo = setInterval(animate, 1000/60);
}
function animate(){
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);// Os if's tem q estar em uma ordem específica onde o if que detecta o movimento tem q estar antes do if q detecta a colisão com o muro.
 //Key detection, that makes the player move.
 if (players.up){
  players.y -= players.speed;
 }
 if (players.down){
  players.y += players.speed;
 }
 if (players.right){
  players.x += players.speed;
 }
 if (players.left){
  players.x -= players.speed;
 }
 // End
 //Detecção de colisão no muro
 if (players.y < 50){
  players.y += players.speed;
 }
 if (players.y > canvas.height - players.height - 50){
  players.y -= players.speed;
 }
 if (players.x < 50){
  players.x += players.speed;
 }
 if (players.x > canvas.width - players.width - 50){
  players.x -= players.speed;
 }
 //end
 ctx.fillStyle = "brown";
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 ctx.lineTo(50,50);
 ctx.moveTo(0,500);
 ctx.lineTo(50,450);
 ctx.moveTo(700,0);
 ctx.lineTo(650,50);
 ctx.moveTo(700,500);
 ctx.lineTo(650,450);
 ctx.strokeRect(50,50,600,400);
 ctx.stroke();
 angleToTurn = -Math.atan2((mouseX-15) - players.x, (mouseY-15) - players.y )*(180/Math.PI);//Pega a posição do players.x e do mouse para criar o angulo de movimento;
 for (var z = 0; z < Orbital.length; z++){
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  orbitals = Orbital[z];
  orbitals.angle = angleToTurn+85;
  orbitals.x = players.x+(orbitals.radius*Math.cos(orbitals.angle*(Math.PI/180)))+(players.width/2)-2;
  orbitals.y = players.y+(orbitals.radius*Math.sin(orbitals.angle*(Math.PI/180)))+(players.height/2)-2;
  if (orbitals.angle > 360){
   orbitals.angle = 0;
  }
  ctx.fillRect(orbitals.x,orbitals.y,orbitals.width,orbitals.height);
 }
    //Here is the part that returns undefined at the console log
 if (tiros >= 1){
  bullets.x += bullets.speedX;
  bullets.y += bullets.speedY;
  document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = "if";
  ctx.fillRect(bullets.x,bullets.y,bullets.width,bullets.height);
 }
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.fillRect(players.x,players.y,players.width,players.height);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="load()">
  <canvas id="box" width="700" height="500"></canvas>
  <button onclick="play()">Go</button>
  <h1 id="demo">Teste</h1>
  <h1 id="demo2"></h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: swap order of `tiros++` and `bullets = Bullet[tiros]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem looks to be that `tiros` is being incremented before being used, when it should be after. Try:

```js
    canvas.onmousedown = function () {
        Bullet.push(new bullet()) 
        bullets = Bullet[tiros++];
        document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = tiros;
    };
```

Comment: Glad to help! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though. Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah, i'am just waiting, it says i need to wait 3 more minutes to accept the answer. Thank you again :)